# Stream iptv channels to tv

Tags: 14.04, streaming, dlna

My provider give me a m3u playlist with iptv channels.
I want to see them on TV with DLNA support.
I use minidlna to see video files from Ubuntu PC on that TV.
But iptv channels aren't files.
How to get these channels on TV ?